# Xamarin "_AndroidXJetifyEmbeddedFiles" Build Error Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

Whenever I try to build and run my mobile project the error

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1166,2):
> error MSB4057: The target "_AndroidXJetifyEmbeddedFiles" does not
> exist in the project.

Even when I create a new xamarin project and run it with the default code, I get the same error. Visual Studios is up to date so I am not sure what the problem could be.

Comment: Did you tried with updating all nugets

Comment: yea still getting the issue

Comment: I'm having the same issue and I'm unable to work on my Android projects. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Nope. just ended up creating a new project and copying and pasting all of the code into new files on my laptop

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by posting on Xamarin-Android's GitHub issue tracker [See here...](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/6095)

You should try to delete `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.migration` and to compile you app again. It worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following methods:

1.update your nuget to the latest version and then delete bin and obj folders and try again;

2.Check if you have set up the Android SDK for Xamarin.Android correctly.
Check document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-sdk?tabs=windows

3.If the problem persists,try to repair your visual studio;
For more details, please check:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019;

4.If the problem persists，you can try to perform a thorough uninstall for Xamarin for Visual Studio, and install the latest Visual Studio;

Comment: I tried all these steps but nothing changed and I'm still facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Today when i update a old project to Xamarin.Form5, i get this bug. I try to update all nuget, but still show this bug, when i see Warning, i see have a nuget downgrade because two nuget reference conflict. I delete one nuget that i not use, Build success.